# How to use data-* attribute with SVG Circle element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to update the css property `fill` of the Circle element (e.g, from blue to red) when it is clicked with the jQuery `.css()` method and through the data-* attribute.

**EXAMPLE:**

**CSS**

```
svg {
  height: 200;
  width: 200;
}
circle {
  fill: blue;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
jQuery(function(){
  $(document).on("click", "[data-update]", function(){
    var circle = $(this).find("circle");
    circle.css({ fill: "red" });
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<svg data-update>
  <circle cy="100" cx="100" r="50"></circle>
</svg>
```

The link for the demo is [here](http://jsbin.com/heravomege/edit?js,output).

So if I add a value (e.g, green) to the `data-update` attribute:

```
data-update="green"
```

Then what particular code should I change or add inside the script in order to change the Circle element's color?

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to get the value of the attribute. [Demo](http://jsbin.com/qosasumaji/1/edit?html,js,console,output).

```
jQuery(function(){
  $(document).on("click", "[data-update]", function(){
    var circle = $(this).find("circle");
    circle.css({
      fill: $(this).data('update') // <-- get value
    });
  });
});

<svg data-update="green">
  <circle cy="100" cx="100" r="50"></circle>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change the code as follows, you will get the result.

```
jQuery(function(){
  $(document).on("click", "svg", function(){
    var circle = $(this).find("circle");
    var color = $(this).data("update");  -- Read the data-update attribute
    circle.css({ fill: color });
  });
});
```